# Finding the previous value in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have table `queue` with values.

```
id name
--------
1  apple
2  mango
3  banana -- I assumed this name, don't remember it exactly
```

But I accidentally changed it to be

```
id name
---------
1  apple
2  mango
3  John
```

So I reverted it back to

```
id name
----------
1  apple
2  mango
3  banana
```

But now I came to know that name is not banana for `id = 3`.

How can I know what used to be there before I changed it?

Comment: You may also want to consider, for future oops, a trigger on this table, to log changes to a history table.

Answer (score 2):

Naturally, if you have a backup before the change, you could simply restore that backup to another database and get the previous value from that.  Otherwise, you 'might' be able to take advantage of the free trial of this 
http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the log hasn't been truncated, you might be able to retrieve it from the log with a little T-SQL and a hex editor.

**Sample Data**

```
create table logscanTest (someID int identity, somevalue nvarchar(255));

insert logscanTest
values ('apple'),('mango'),('cherry');

update logscanTest set somevalue='John' where somevalue = 'cherry';
update logscanTest set somevalue='banana' where somevalue = 'John';
```

You can use the following code to retrieve `UPDATE` transactions.  You will want to change the following values to match your critera:

- AllocUnitName - this should match the schema.tableName of your table
- [Begin Time]  - this should match the earliest date you know the value was correct

**Code**

```
SELECT 
    [Lock Information],[RowLog Contents 0], [RowLog Contents 1] 
FROM 
    fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE
    Operation = 'LOP_MODIFY_ROW'
    AND AllocUnitName='dbo.logscanTest'
    AND [Transaction ID] IN (
        SELECT [Transaction ID] FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
        WHERE   [Begin Time]       > '2016/09/01 11:35'
            AND [Transaction Name] = 'UPDATE')
```

[image: QueryResults]

This will give you the lock information, before, and after values for the update.  The lock info will give you the page that was modified.  You can use DBCC PAGE to verify you are looking at the correct transaction.  Use the values from `ACQUIRE_LOCK_IX` in the command.  In the code example below, these values are 5,1,344 - database id 5, partition 1, page 344.  The last value is reporting style, and 3 gives the most detail on the individual records.

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604);
DBCC PAGE (5, 1, 344, 3);
DBCC TRACEOFF (3604);
GO
```

Once you are sure you have the right transaction, use the [RowLog Contents 0]  (before) value and [RowLog Contents 1] (after) value to determine what the value was before it was changed.  You can paste the value (without the 0x) into a hex editor to view the contents.

In my example, the values are 0x1B006300680065007200720079 and 0x17004A006F0068006E.  Pasting the values, sans 0x, results in values `cherry` and `John`, telling me this is the correct transaction and the previous value was `cherry`.

[image: Hex]